# Using multilingual names in OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, internationalization, translation

In OpenStreetMap one can set building names for each building.

Available is for example:

`name` as default name and `name:de` for its German translation.

Example:

`name Italian Restaurant`

`name:de Italienisches Restaurant`

However, with this syntax in openstreetmap.de both names are displayed in the map, positioned below each other (which looks very ugly). How can I avoid this behavior, so only one name is displayed (in case of German visitor = German name preferred)?

Comment: Are you asking as a OSM contributor or as someone making or trying to use a particular OSM client application (e.g. an embedded map)?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer.

If you visit https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers you'll see you're using the "German fork of the Standard tile layer" which is described as "label in German and local language (transliterated where no name in Latin script is available)".

There are many other tile servers available on this page, but I don't see any that use only the German name. I thought [http://öpnvkarte.de/](http://%C3%B6pnvkarte.de/) might do this, but it doesn't.

If none of the existing tile servers do what you want, you could try creating one yourself: it's not trivial, but it's not that difficult either.

Answer (score 0):

the tiles used at https://www.osmap.de show only the German name as label (or - if no German name is available in OSM data - the English name or a transscription in latin script).